# JavaScript website error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am trying to make a website With just JavaScript but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'at html:12:9
```

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var divEl = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(divEl);
        var ptag = document.createElement("p").setAttribute("id", "lol");
        divEl.appendChild(ptag);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.createElement("p").setAttribute("id", "lol");` does not return a node.

Answer (score 3):

`setAttribute` does not return a node, so your `ptag` variable is getting set to `undefined`.

From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

> Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on
>   the specified element. Returns undefined.

Try calling `setAttribute` in a separate statement:

```
<script>
    var divEl = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(divEl);
    var ptag = document.createElement("p");
    ptag.setAttribute("id", "lol");
    divEl.appendChild(ptag);
</script>
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wibeyewuqo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

As @vlaz pointed out, `setAttribute()` doesn't return a node. Call this on ptag after creating it:

```
var divEl = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(divEl);
var ptag = document.createElement("p");
ptag.setAttribute("id", "lol");
divEl.appendChild(ptag);
```